# How to execute a javascript through a broswer made in Swift 3?

Tags: javascript, swift, swift3

I'm making a broswer in Swift for iOS. I want to execute a script while it's opening a page. The script for like clicking a button and etc.
What should I do?

Comment: As far as I know, you can either use Javascript or Swift, not both in combination. [Here's an article](https://sallar.me/app-journey/) about building apps the JS versus the Swift way. Although it seems to be possible to call JS from Swift and the other way around as [described here](https://tetontech.wordpress.com/2014/07/15/swift-to-javascript-and-javascript-to-swift-a-round-trip/).